# Why am I getting the error: "Value of type UICollectionView has no member dequeueReusableCell"?

Tags: ios, swift3

I a reading a book from "Hacking with Swift" by: Paul Hudson. I am following all the steps, but a few days ago i touched something I think I shouldn't. I've now been getting this Error for the past day's and I've used this same method before and it worked but I don't know what happened or what I touched. Can anyone help me?

Here's my Code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UICollectionViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Person", for: indexPath) as! PersonCell
    return cell
}


}
```

Comment: The code you posted looks fine and it compiles without error. The problem must lie somewhere else. Can add you add more details to your question?

Comment: Basically i was following the book and the book didn't mention any errors that would happen. Also, I've used this method before and it worked. I think i touched something i shouldn't have in one of the UICollectionView.h files. I hope this can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this - it will work in swift 2.x. Your code works in swift3.

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(self.premiumCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
```

Comment: Thanks Taimur this really helped.